# iterating on a list of vectors of some class (C++)

Tags: c++, list, vector, iterator, containers

Can anyone help me with why this code give me a segmentation fault on the inner loop?
I am trying to iterate on a list of vectors of some class block.

```
class chain
{
    list<vector<Block*>* >* _blockChain;
}

Chain* someChain = new Chain();

for(list<vector<Block*>*>::iterator listIter = someChain->getChain()->end() ;
        listIter != someChain->getChain()->begin(); listIter--)
{
    for(vector<Block*>::iterator it = (*listIter)->begin();
        it != (*listIter)->end() ; it++)
    {
         //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably because you're using far too many pointers. If you want a specific answer, you'll need to [demonstrate the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to iterate through the list in reverse, use a reverse_iterator:

```
for(list<vector<Block*>*>::reverse_iterator listIter = someChain->getChain()->rbegin();
        listIter != someChain->getChain()->rend(); ++listIter)
```

With a recent compiler you can condense that down a bit:

```
for (auto listIter = someChain->getChain()->rbegin();
            listIter != someChain->getChain()->rend(); ++listIter)
```

That said, I agree with @Mike Seymour: you are using *way* too many pointers. For one really obvious example, there's almost never a reason to use a pointer to a vector (because a vector is itself little more than a wrapper around a pointer to data, with a little extra data for book-keeping about how much data is in the vector).

Answer (score 1):

The first time you try to access `listIter` it is pointing to `end()` which is not to be dereferenced.  In the inner loop you dereference `listIter` and try to use it.

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end

> This element acts as a placeholder; attempting to access it results in undefined behavior.

Comment: thanks, can i ask you how can i iterate on a list from the end to the beginning?

Comment: @MiddleMan see Jerry Coffin's answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you face a crash in `List::end()` and `List::begin()`. It's because you has not initialized your `List` anywhere in your code (at least I don't see in your given code). you need:

```
class Chain{

    Chain()
    {
        _blockChain = new list<vector<int*>* >;
        // initializing Vector and so on
    }
};
```

Although this is not all of your problems.